# Copy Shop database design

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a database and am wondering if my design makes any sense at all.

I'm trying to design a database for a small internal Copy Shop to track orders and price jobs.  I thought creating a relational database would be a good way to store this info.  A couple examples of typical orders would be:

- Order #1: 100 sets of 7 B&W pages and 3 color pages, stapled, on plain 20lb 8.5x11 paper
- Order #2: One 24" x 36" poster laminated and mounted on foamcore

The design I started working on was this:
[image: database design]

So for example, I have:

- Products: {Copy Order, Poster}
- Attributes: {B&W Pages, Color Pages, Sets, Stapling, Paper Size, Paper Type, Poster Size}
- Attribute Options: {Staple Upper-Left, ..., 8.5x11, ..., Plain 20lb, ..., 24" x 36", ...}

So far I think this is reasonable.  What I can't figure out is how to add pricing profiles. The problem is that the price of an attribute option depends on other attribute options, and it's different in every case.  Using the examples above:

- The price of Order #1: [price of B&W prints on plain 8.5x11 paper]x[number of B&W pages] + [price of color prints on plain 8.5x11 paper]x[number of color pages] + [number of sets]x[price of staples]
- The price of Order #2: [price of 24x36 poster laminated and mounted on foamcore]x[quantity of posters]

Additionally, we charge different prices for different types of customers, so I planned on having multiple price profiles.

Is there any reasonable way to do this in a relational database?  Or should I do it some other way?  The existing database is poorly designed (by me, a few years ago) and has most of the attributes hard-coded as field names, with separate tables for each product.  So for example, paper_type is a field in the copy_orders table and poster_size is a field in the poster_orders table.  And I use code to calculate the price.  I'd like to design something better and more flexible.

I'm (clearly) not an expert on relational databases, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to provide an Entity Relationship Table for quicker replies.

Comment: Is the image I attached not enough?  I'm not sure what else to upload - is there a better way to upload the diagram?

Comment: ERT tables include 1:1, 1:many like relation ships as well as shared columns like foreign keys. You may try to export one from your scheme.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, I was a bit lazy there and haven't defined them yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as usual is "it depends".  Taking your first example:

```
The price of Order #1: [price of B&W prints on plain 8.5x11 paper]x[number of B&W pages] + [price of color prints on plain 8.5x11 paper]x[number of color pages] + [number of sets]x[price of staples]
```

You need to have three parts (or items, or products, or SKUs): b&w print on plain 8.5X11 paper, color print on plain 8.5X11 paper and staples. Each of these parts has a price (there is a problem here connected with maintaining a history of prices and ensuring that you get the current price per part, but I'll ignore that for now). Then the price of order #1 becomes

```
amount of part1 * price of part1 +
amount of part2 * price of part2 +
amount of part3 * price of part3
```

For the second example, you would have to define a part called '24x36 poster laminated and mounted on foamcore' then define its price.

If the cost of attributes can be assigned a percentage (eg a color print cost 25% more than a b&w print [although maybe these days it's the other way around]), then you define a part 'print on plain 8.5x11 paper' and assign it a price. In your attributes table, you add a 'percentage extra price' field and insert a value of 25 (or 0.25 or 1.25, depending on how you want to manage things) for the attribute 'color print'.

As for customers, one way of treating this is to define a constant discount which each customer receives from the price list. If a customers gets a different discount per part then you have no option but to define a table with three fields - customer id, part id and price.

Although this seems complicated, in the end it's the best way.

Comment: Thanks, No'am.  It does seem complicated, so I've decided to shelve this project until I have more time to devote to it and possibly simplify the operations.